# Rails routes for js file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, service-worker

I got a ServiceWorker made with a webpack plugin that is public available with `http://example.com/packs/sw.js` URL. Since I want this Service Worker to control the whole website I need to serve it from `http://example.com/`. So, no `redirect_to` allowed
How do I have to set the `routes.rb` for this?

What I've tried is:

Added : `get '/sw' => 'sw#show'` to `routes.rb`
Created controller `sw_controller.rb`:

```
require 'net/http'

class SwController < ActionController::Base
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.all {
        uri = URI('http://example.com/packs/sw.js')
        res = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
        render inline: res
      }
    end
  end
end
```

It's ugly I know but should work:

- Visiting `http://example.com/sw.js` gives `No route matches [GET] "/sw.js"`
- Visiting `http://example.com/packs/sw.js` prints out the service worker correctly
- Visiting `http://example.com/sw` prints out the service worker correctly
- Also visiting `http://example.com/sw.lol` print the serviceworker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **config/initializers/mime_types.rb** try adding:

```
Mime::Type.register "text/javascript", :js
```

This should allow `format.all` to recognise the Javascript request, which it will otherwise ignore.

Source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html

Comment: I think this goes on the right way but doesn't resolve the problem. Things keep unchanged (yes I've restarted the server a few times). I've also tried `application/javascript` but nothing changes. The GET request for `http://example.com/sw.js` has also no headers and keep giving me `No route matches [GET] "/sw.js"`

Comment: what happens if you run `rake routes` ? Does it show your route?

Comment: Yes, route exists in fact visiting `http://example.com/sw` prints out the service worker correctly but visiting `http://example.com/sw.js` gives `No route matches [GET] "/sw.js"` [image confirms](https://i.imgur.com/vc3JCR5.png)

Comment: ok, so I've never tried this... does `get '/sw.js' => 'sw#show'` do anything?

Comment: **Solved**. The problem was about the webpack plugin which in some way altered routes.  I changed the serviceworker name end extension and now works

Comment: I'm pleased you sorted it. Might be worth posting your solution as an answer, since that was the thing that actually resolved the issue for you.